# Line integral - why is $ds= \dfrac{ds}{dt}dt$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

I’ve been reading on my own about this because it’s on the syllabus of the next semester and I’m very confused on something about the line integral.

I have the curve C with parametrization $C(t)=(x(t),y(t)),$ $a\leq t\leq b.$ Then

$$\int_C f(x,y)ds= \int_a^b f(x(t),y(t))\dfrac{ds}{dt}dt.$$

I am okay until they do this: $ds= \dfrac{ds}{dt}dt.$ i don’t understand this. Is it the chain rule?

I was reading Zill’s calculus but it’s not clear for me. Sorry if I’m asking very poorly, and I’m sorry if my questions is because I lack a better foundation in vector theory.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: It's essentially the definition of the $ds$ term in the integral.  If you carefully parse the definition of the integral including the $ds$ bit you can usually use the Mean Value Theorem to deduce what you want.

Comment: It is the Change of variable : we are changing $s$ to $t$ , hence we have to change $ds$ to $dt$ , where we have to introduce the term $ds/dt$ : Integral limits will change from $C$ to $(a,b)$ : the function should be written in terms of $t$ : Everything else will be unchanged !

Comment: For a general function $F(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ of $n$ variables, its "differential" is defined as the expression $dF = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial F}{\partial x_i} dx_i$. In the case that $s = s(t)$ depends on only one variable, this definition reduces to $ds = \frac{ds}{dt} dt$. Essentially as Randall commented above, it is the definition of "differential" of a function, in this case the function s (as a function of t), where s is the length of the curve being integrated over.

Answer (score 1):

> I am okay until they do this: $ds= \dfrac{ds}{dt}dt.$. i don’t understand this

Its needed to put the integral into terms of the variable  *t* since the variables *x* and *y* are functions of *t* and also the limits of integration are in terms of *t*. Think of ds/dt as the Jacobian.